# Disable App Engine Instance/Server during hours to reduce costs

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I wish to shutdown my node server running on google app engine during night times to reduce server costs and start it back up again in the morning. 11pm - 11am.

Is there anyway to turn off the app engine via running a function on the server itself?

I would then run another function via an external server to start the server/instance up again.

Answer (score 0):

To enable or disable your App Engine application, you can use the [apps.patch method](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps/patch) from the [App Engine Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/).

You have to use these parameters:

**Path parameters:**

```
name = apps/[project-id]
```

**Query parameters:**

```
updateMask = servingStatus
```

**Request body:**

*To enable your application:*

```
{
  "servingStatus": "SERVING"
}
```

*To disable your application:*

```
{
  "servingStatus": "USER_DISABLED"
}
```

Comment: I have run this through cloud scheduler.

https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/[APP-ID]/services/default/?updateMask=servingStatus

POST

{
  "servingStatus": "USER_DISABLED"
}

I get 404 status:  "NOT_FOUND"