# shutting down GCP basic scaled app engine every day at a certain time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions

my company has a small B1 basic scaled node js server on app engine, the server is used to log employee clock ins and outs everyday.

My firm recently upgraded to a newer fingerprint timesheet scanner, and I noticed our server which has been running free for the past year or so has suddenly accumulated cost this month.

I realised what happened is no one actually clocks in/out between 1 am and 7 am, but the fingerprint machine is periodically sending get requests to the server every 30 or so mins, causing it to spin up and start an instance. Whereas the old machine would only send a request whenever a user clocked in/out.

We already use our F instance to run 24 hrs to host our company website and i dont want to run manual scaling as it forces the app to run even though there are 0 requests coming in.

Also, since GCP offers only 18 hours of free B1 app engine per day, I thought I could simply stop the server between the hours of 1 am to 7 am, by creating a cloud function that turns off the server at 1 am everyday, and another that turns the server back on at 7 am and was wondering if this is even possible? I did some readings and it looks possible, but I cant find any examples outside of using manual scaling online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres what I ended up doing:

1. Deployed a google cloud function that toggles my app engine service on and off.
2. Use cloud scheduler to trigger it every day at a certain time.

cloud function:

```
const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

functions.http('toggleFingerprintServer', async (req, res) => {
    const externalRes = await fetch('https://content-appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/:appname/services/:service-name/versions/1', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ servingStatus: req.query.servingStatus }),
    });
    res.sendStatus(externalRes.ok ? 200 : 500);
});
```

Now all you have to do is use cloud scheduler to trigger the function everyday.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can see 2 options:

- Either, switch from App Engine to Cloud Run. More suitable for the future and for this king of use case. And because you pay only when you use Cloud Run (rounded to the upper 100ms) it's cheaper than AppEngine (where you pay 15 minutes after the latest request. I wrote a comparison in an [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-vs-app-engine-whats-the-lowest-cost-6c82b874ed61)
- Or, turn of the application. But you can't! The only way is to deploy another version that not listen the endpoint, or change the app engine handlers to not expose/route the traffic to your instance between 1 and 7am. But.... I don't like this solution. If your job that redeploy the App Engine fail, your service will be unavailable. I prefer the Cloud Run solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this [documentation](https://www.edureka.co/community/167292/gcp-auto-shutdown-and-startup-using-google-cloud-schedulers) where they provided a sample code on turning off and on a nodejs. Instead of using a Cloud Function, they used Cloud Scheduler.

There is a suggestion from [sotis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55275868/disable-app-engine-instance-server-during-hours-to-reduce-costs), that suggested using [apps.patch](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps/patch) method from [App Engine Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api)

They provided to use the said parameters:

Path parameters:

```
name = apps/[project-id]
```

Query parameters:

```
updateMask = servingStatus Request body:
```

To enable your application:

```
{ "servingStatus": "SERVING" }
```

To disable your application:

```
{ "servingStatus": "USER_DISABLED" }
```